# Finding joint CDF from joint PDF.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint density 
>   $$
> f(x,y) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             1/\pi & \quad\text{if}\ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 \\
>             0 & \quad \mathrm {otherwise}
>         \end{array}
>     \right.$$
>   Find the joint CDF of $X$ and $Y$.

How do I proceed? Please help me as I am a beginner of this topic.

Comment: Should the joint PDF be $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(x)$?

Comment: Yeah it should be $f(x,y)$ instead of $f(x)$. I apologize for that. I have corrected my error.

Comment: The distribution is uniform. Plotting a graph should be useful.

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem unfortunately! But the joint CDF you mention is interesting. $F(1,1)$ evaluates to $\frac{2}{\pi}$ but I think it would evaluate to $1$.

Comment: Could you add how did you arrive at this answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think the joint CDF $F(x,y)= \mathbb P(X \le x,Y \le Y)$ may be fairly involved, and looking at this diagram suggests the following to me:

[image]

- If $x \le -1$, or if $y \le -1$, or if $x \le 0$ and $y \le 0$ and $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$:

$$F(x,y)=0$$

- If $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$:

$$F(x,y)=1$$

- If  $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $y \ge 1$, or if $-1 \le x \le 0$ and $0 \le y \le 1$ and $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$:

$$F(x,y)= \frac1\pi\left( \frac\pi 2 +  \sin^{-1}(x) +  x\sqrt{1-x^2} \right)$$

- If  $x \ge 1$ and  $-1 \le y \le 1$, or if $0 \le x \le 1$ and  $-1 \le y \le 0$ and $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$:

$$F(x,y)= \frac1\pi\left( \frac\pi 2 +  \sin^{-1}(y) +  y\sqrt{1-y^2} \right)$$

- If  $0 \le x \le 1$ and  $0 \le y \le 1$ and $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$:

$$F(x,y)= \frac1\pi\left( \sin^{-1}(x)+  \sin^{-1}(y) +  x\sqrt{1-x^2}  + y\sqrt{1-y^2} \right)$$

- If  $x^2+y^2 \le 1$:

$$F(x,y)= \frac1\pi\left( \frac\pi 4 + \frac1{2}\sin^{-1}(x) + \frac1{2} \sin^{-1}(y) +  \frac1{2} x \sqrt{1-x^2} + \frac1{2}y \sqrt{1-y^2} + x y \right)$$

The interesting parts of the marginal CDFs for $X$ and $Y$ are in the third and fourth points above respectively

Comment: I'm glad someone tackled this question... my beginner integration skills don't cut it at all for weird shapes. Just curious... did you use a program or website to draw that diagram? Also what level of calculus do you need to do what you did... would you say advanced HS calculus or something more? thanks...

Comment: @HJ_beginner: I used MS Paint for the picture. As for the probabilities, it involved finding the area of a sector, subtracting the area of an oblique triangle based on its co-ordinates (so leaving a segment) and adding the area of a right triangle then tidying up and checking the various cases, so trigonometry rather than calculus. You may be able to use calculus if you have the skills to find $\int \sqrt{1-x^2} \, dx = \frac12 \sin^{-1}(x) + \frac12 x \sqrt{1-x^2}  +c$ but I did not actually use this

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach. Well outside of the math at least I have the skills right now to replicate the MS paint part -_-